# How to register `Amazon Cognito` users with an AWS Lambda Java function?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

How to register users to `Amazon Cognito` using an `AWS Lambda` function? Amazon docs are available only for `Javascript`. I would like to write it in `Java`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have aws sdk (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html). If you check through the left pannel you can seek for services, like CognitoIdentity.

Anyway, if I'm not wrong, some Cognito functions are made to be used from frontend, for instance the registration part. Your users should introduce their email in frontend and there you call Cognito functions to send them the confirmation email. That's why most of the examples are made in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS documentation is not very good about Cognito and the API's. It's not just a Java SDK problem. Basically you will need to execute the following actions:

1. Get one [AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidp/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient.html) or AWSCognitoIdentityProviderAsyncClient using a builder;
2. Create a SignUpRequest and configure it with the information of the new user;
3. Call the SignUp method in the AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClient using
   the SignUpRequest as a parameter and check for the SignUpResult.

But keep in mind that are a lot more actions that need to be done in this process. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html) you'll find more information.